# How to open a file in default application but don't open a new instance if not necessary

Tags: default-programs

What's the command in Ubuntu Linux that's equivalent to `open` and `open -n` in Mac OS X?

In Ubuntu, I usually use

```
gnome-open file
xdg-open file
```

to open a file with the default program/application for the file type from command line. However, regardless if an instance of the program/application is already open/running, that will open a new instance, which is sometimes not really desirable. In most cases, I just want to open another file in the existing instance. In Mac OS X, I control this by choosing `open -n file` (force open a new instance) or `open file` (use existing instance).

Comment: Now it is `xdg-open` but still no way to use existing open application.